# Referencing a Android library in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, dll, xamarin.android, android-library

I have created a xamarin android library with another third party component.

In the referencing project, i have to include the library referenced component as well even if i am not using it. Is there any way to avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean **[Binding a Java Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/)** ,

The third-party library ecosystem for Android is massive. Because of this, it frequently makes sense to use an existing Android library than to create a new one. Xamarin.Android offers two ways to use these libraries:

- Create a Bindings Library that automatically wraps the library with C# wrappers so you can invoke Java code via C# calls.
- Use the Java Native Interface (JNI) to invoke calls in Java library code directly. JNI is a programming framework that enables Java code to call and be called by native applications or libraries.

A Bindings Library is an assembly containing Managed Callable Wrappers for Java types. For example, here is a Java type, `MyClass`, that we want to wrap in a Bindings Library:

```
package com.xamarin.mycode;

public class MyClass
{
    public String myMethod (int i) { ... }
}
```

After we generate a Bindings Library for the **.jar** that contains `MyClass`, we can instantiate it and call methods on it from C#:

```
var instance = new MyClass ();

string result = instance.MyMethod (42);
```